# Erro no arduino (ponteiro para struct)

Tags: c, ponteiro, arduino

Estou tentando fazer a definição de tipos abaixo mas o Arduino acusa erro de declaração de tipos.

```
/*Estrutura que abstrai a seringa*/
struct {
  int pot[7];
  float nivel[7] = {0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3};
} seri;

/*Definição do tipo de dado abstrato Seringa*/
typedef struct seri Seringa;

/*Instanciação da variável seringa (minúsculo) do tipo Seringa (maiúsculo)*/
Seringa *seringa;

seringa = malloc(sizeof(struct seri));
```

> *Arduino: 1.8.10 (Linux), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"
>   seringa:18:1: error: 'seringa' does not name a type
>    seringa = malloc(sizeof(struct seri));

Answer (score 0):

Tente retirar o `typedef struct`

```
/*Estrutura que abstrai a seringa*/
struct {
  int pot[7];
  float nivel[7] = {0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3};
} seri;

/*Definição do tipo de dado abstrato Seringa*/
seri Seringa; /* <- aqui */

/*Instanciação da variável seringa (minúsculo) do tipo Seringa (maiúsculo)*/
Seringa *seringa;

seringa = malloc(sizeof(struct seri));
```

Comment: Continua dando o mesmo erro.

Answer (score 0):

Voçê não definiu corretamente o nome `Seringa`.

A maneira correta é:

```
typedef struct {
  int pot[7];
  float nivel[7] = {0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3};
} Seringa;

Seringa *seringa;

seringa = malloc(sizeof(Seringa));
```

Ou:

```
struct Seringa{
  int pot[7];
  float nivel[7] = {0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3};
};

typedef struct Seringa Seringa;

Seringa *seringa;

seringa = malloc(sizeof(Seringa));
```

O `typedef` nesse caso serve apenas para evitar estar sempre a escrever `struct` cada vez que referir ao tipo da estrutura. Poderia ser feito dessa forma, sem usar `typedef`:

```
struct Seringa{
  int pot[7];
  float nivel[7] = {0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3};
};

struct Seringa *seringa;

seringa = malloc(sizeof(struct Seringa));
```

Além disso não é possível chamar uma função no escopo global. A chamada de `malloc` deve ser feita dentro de outra função, por exemplo, dentro de da função `setup` da API do Arduino.

Comment: Em ambos os casos continua dando erro..

Comment: Embora não testei, estou convencido de que não tem nenhum erro aí. Consegue enviar um link para o código completo?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_fR4Sij5vfxUFCdjaEUhpy6ZJhTSc5TN9YjfxEcK-mg

Comment: Você está chamando a função `malloc` no escopo glogal, não é possível fazer isso em `C`. O ponteiro `seringa` deve ser inicializado dentro de uma função, por exemplo, dentro de `setup`.

Comment: Hmmm, nao sabia disso. Muito obrigado!